# SMTP Delivery Failure Headers

Tags: exchange, smtp-headers, microsoft-dfo365

hoping someone could help me out.  I'm sending out SMTP email with a custom header, e.g x-commId and for a successful email, this header is shown in the received message header (Which is not when I actually need it).

When I send this to an invalid address, the failed response strips out this header (exchange didn't do this). I need this commId to initiate a fallback and disable the email address (via automation). Does anyone have any thought how I could get around this problem of the header going missing.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, Microsoft Exchange 2010 includes a feature called a header firewall that strips X-headers from untrusted sources (the internet) and this sort of thing exists in some SMTP security gateways too. Many admins will strip almost all non-critical headers off a message as it leaves to obscure any internal information.

For more details: [Header firewall](https://docs.microsoft.com/EN-US/exchange/header-firewall-exchange-2013-help?redirectedfrom=MSDN)